Checking to see if a value exists in array
I am coding tic tac toe and trying to figure out a way to check to see if a position has been filled before making the desired move. The solution that I derived that came to me the most naturally was to initialize an empty list, for the first move make it as the list is empty, and for all subsequent moves check against the list, if the move is in the list, don't make it, else make it.
class Tictactoe:
    def __init__(self,playerone,playertwo):
        self.playerone = playerone
        self.playertwo = playertwo
        self.made_moves = []

    def makeMove(self):
        marker = "O"
        xcoor,ycoor = self.getMove()

        #if first move, make the move
        if len(self.made_moves)== 0:
            self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
            self.made_moves += (xcoor,ycoor)
        
        #for all other moves, check to see if the position is filled
        else:
            if [xcoor,ycoor] in self.made_moves:
                print(f"The position at {xcoor,ycoor} is already full, please try again.")
            else:
                self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
                self.made_moves += xcoor,ycoor

        return

However, when I run my program, it is still allowing moves to be made where there is already a marker there and I'm not sure why. When I first did this, I had initialized the empty list in the makeMove class, and I figured the issue was that each time the loop ran the makeMove class it would reinitialize the empty list, so I moved it to init that way it would just exit there, yet I am still running into the same issue.
Full code if needed:
class Tictactoe:
    def __init__(self,playerone,playertwo):
        self.playerone = playerone
        self.playertwo = playertwo
        self.made_moves = []

    def newBoard(self):
        # creates new board
        self.board = [[None, None, None],
                 [None, None, None],
                 [None, None, None]
                 ]

    def renderBoard(self):
        # Prints current state of the board
        for row in self.board:
            print("|", end="")
            for cell in row:
                if cell is None:
                    print("   |", end="")
                else:
                    print(f" {cell} |", end="")
            print("\n" + "-" * 13)

    def getMove(self):
        print("Coordinates must range from 0 to 2, 0 corresponding to the first row/column, 
        onwards")
        xcoor = int(input("What is your x coordinate?"))
        ycoor = int(input("What is your y coordinate?"))
        
        if xcoor not in {0,1,2} or ycoor not in {0,1,2}:
            print("Coordinates must be between 0 and 2")
        
        return xcoor,ycoor

    def makeMove(self):
        marker = "O"
        xcoor,ycoor = self.getMove()

        #if first move, make the move
        if len(self.made_moves)== 0:
            self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
            self.made_moves += (xcoor,ycoor)
        
        #for all other moves, check to see if the position is filled
        else:
            if [xcoor,ycoor] in self.made_moves:
                print(f"The position at {xcoor,ycoor} is already full, please try again.")
            else:
                self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
                self.made_moves += xcoor,ycoor

    def getWinner(self):
        #todo write win conditions
        '''if player one marks 3 in a row, player one wins, end game
        if player two marks 3 in a row, player 2 wins, end game
        '''
        pass

    def resetButton(self):
        #todo: create a reset button that clears the board.
        pass

    def runGame(self):
            test = Tictactoe("playerone", "playertwo")
            print(test.newBoard())
            for i in range(9):
                print(test.makeMove())
                print(test.renderBoard())
            print("Game Over, it is a draw")
    
    def isBoardFull(self):
        #todo: write code that checks if board is full
        pass

    def main():
        test = Tictactoe("playerone", "playertwo",)
        print(test.runGame())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


thank you for posting this question - I learned something from debugging your issue :)
Here is the portion of your snippet that is causing the bug:
    if len(self.made_moves)== 0:
        self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
        self.made_moves += (xcoor,ycoor)
    else:
        if [xcoor,ycoor] in self.made_moves:
            print(f"The position at {xcoor,ycoor} is already full")

You are attempting to add the current move to the move set and I'm assuming you are expecting this:
>>> self.made_moves += (xcoor,ycoor)
[(x, y)]

Instead this appends both items to your list (I didn't know you could do this!) so you get:
[x, y]

One way to fix this would be to call append instead:
self.made_moves.append((xcoor, ycoor))

The second issue then comes up on this line:
if [xcoor,ycoor] in self.made_moves

Here you have a list but in your previous line you are using a tuple. These will never evaluate as true because the types are different:
>>> [1, 2] in [(1, 2)]
False

I would personally use a tuple here because you want to represent that your coordinates are immutable. So overall the fix would be:
    if len(self.made_moves) == 0:
        self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
        self.made_moves.append((xcoor,ycoor))
    else:
        if (xcoor,ycoor) in self.made_moves:
            print(f"The position at {xcoor,ycoor} is already full")


I really have to make many assumptions while reading your code, hopefully I'll explain them in the comment.
My solution is basically the same as Mark's except for small improvements based on my assumptions. So if you want some code that runs and can be tested, here it is:
class Tictactoe:

    def __init__(self,playerone,playertwo):
        self.board = []
        for i in range(3):
            self.board.append([])
            for j in range(3):
                self.board[i].append([])
                
        self.playerone = playerone
        self.playertwo = playertwo
        self.made_moves = []
    
    def makeMove(self, player, coors):
        marker = "O" if player == self.playerone else "1"
        xcoor,ycoor = coors

        #Actually it works irrespective of your move is the first one or not
        if (xcoor,ycoor) in self.made_moves:
            print(f"The position at {xcoor,ycoor} is already full, please try again.")
        else:
            self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
            self.made_moves.append((xcoor,ycoor))
            
    def getWinner(self):
        #todo write win conditions
        '''if player one marks 3 in a row, player one wins, end game
        if player two marks 3 in a row, player 2 wins, end game
        '''
        pass
    
    def resetButton(self):
        #todo: create a reset button that clears the board.
        pass        

    def renderBoard(self):
        print(self.board)

    def newBoard(self):
        print("Reinitialising the board...")
        self.__init__("playerone", "playertwo") # quick and dirty
    
    def runGame(self):
        test = Tictactoe("playerone", "playertwo")
        test.newBoard()
        test.makeMove("playerone", (0, 0))
        test.makeMove("playertwo", (0, 0)) # Here I expect it to reject this position because it was full

        test.newBoard()

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                test.makeMove("playerone" if (3 * i + j) % 2 == 0 else "playertwo", (i, j))
                test.renderBoard()
        
        print("Game Over, it is a draw")
    
    def isBoardFull(self):
        #todo: write code that checks if board is full
        pass

def main():
    test = Tictactoe("playerone", "playertwo",)
    print(test.runGame())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

